# jQuery, function not called from HTML component loaded with ".innerHTML()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class

I have some jQuery functions that are working, like:

```
$(".selector").bind("change blur",function()
{
        $(this).css({"background-size": "22px 22px"});
        $(this).siblings('span').css({"display": "block"});
        $(this).css({"border": 'solid 1px #E85131'});
        $(this).css({"color":'#bbb'});
});
```

when I load my document, every "selector" class are calling that function properly.

Sometimes I update a div with

```
function test()
{
    document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML = "";
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("feed").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "load_feed.php, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

some new div with "selector" class are loaded but they don't call the jQuery code on blur or change.

The one that were already loaded still works.

Do you guys have any idea why?

Comment: Note that jQuery has some AJAX facilities that take care of creating the proper request object for you... http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Just want to note: `xmlhttp.open("POST", "load_feed.php, false)` is missing a closing quote.

Comment: yep thanks for the quote, just my copy past form my file to here ;)

Answer (score 3):

Because that's how bind() works, you need to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead. It allows delegated event binding, while bind() works only for those present at the time of the call. So this is what you need to do:

```
$(document).on("change blur", ".selector", function(){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

like Shomz says, you need to use the 'on' statement instead of 'bind'. You need to do that with every function that is called after the DOM is modified, so if you add something dinamically jquery won't find the ids also if they're correct.

```
$(".selector").bind("change blur",function()
{
        $(this).css({"background-size": "22px 22px"});
        $(this).siblings('span').css({"display": "block"});
        $(this).css({"border": 'solid 1px #E85131'});
        $(this).css({"color":'#bbb'});
});
```

need to became

```
$(document).on(".selector", "change blur", function()
{
        $(this).css({"background-size": "22px 22px"});
        $(this).siblings('span').css({"display": "block"});
        $(this).css({"border": 'solid 1px #E85131'});
        $(this).css({"color":'#bbb'});
});
```

Comment: Thnaks for the extra info, it will help me for sure :)